# Populate textbox based on Dropdown selection - JS

Tags: javascript, html

Here am not able to add text inside the text box based on the dropdown selection.

example: If I Choose `option2` in the dropdown the textbox will filled as `option2`

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    setInterval(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('ddid')) {
                console.log('Found Tag dropdown button');
                return;
            }
            var widgetcontentwrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-content-wrapper');
            if (widgetcontentwrapper.length > 0) {
                console.log('Found widgetcontentwrapper controls');
                var buttonToolbar = widgetcontentwrapper[0].children[0];

                //Create array of options to be added
                var array = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"];

                //Create and append select list
                var selectList = document.createElement("select");
                selectList.setAttribute('class', 'ddclass');
                selectList.setAttribute('id', 'ddid');
                //myParent.appendChild(selectList);
                selectList.addEventListener('change', favTutorial, false);

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.setAttribute('class', 'flex-item');
                div.appendChild(selectList);
                buttonToolbar.insertBefore(div, buttonToolbar.firstChild);

                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = array[i];
                    option.text = array[i];
                    selectList.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
        },
        3000)

    function favTutorial() {
        var mylist = document.getElementsByClassname("ddclass");
        document.getElementsByClassname("input-large").value = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
    }
}
)()
```

```html
<div class="widget-content-wrapper">
          <div class="arrow"></div>
          <form class="input-compressed"><fieldset>
              <legend class="offscreen">
                Add a Tag
              </legend>
              <div class="editable-field-change">
                <span class="input-append input-smaller"><input class="input-large" data-link="proposedTag" placeholder="Add a tag (any text)..." size="16" type="text">
</span>
              </div>
              <div class="tags">
                <ul class="unstyled editable-list inline-list"></ul>
              </div>
            </fieldset></form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here. Firstly, the method is `getElementsByClassName()`, not `getElementsByClassname()` - note the uppercase 'N'.

Secondly, that method returns an array-like object, not a single Element object. Therefore you can't call `value` or `options` on it directly. Given that there's only 1 instance of the element in the question you can just use `[0]` to access the first element in the set.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('ddid')) {
      console.log('Found Tag dropdown button');
      return;
    }
    
    var widgetcontentwrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-content-wrapper');
    if (widgetcontentwrapper.length > 0) {
      var buttonToolbar = widgetcontentwrapper[0].children[0];

      //Create array of options to be added
      var array = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"];

      //Create and append select list
      var selectList = document.createElement("select");
      selectList.setAttribute('class', 'ddclass');
      selectList.setAttribute('id', 'ddid');
      //myParent.appendChild(selectList);
      selectList.addEventListener('change', favTutorial, false);

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('class', 'flex-item');
      div.appendChild(selectList);
      buttonToolbar.insertBefore(div, buttonToolbar.firstChild);

      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array[i];
        option.text = array[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }, 3000)

  function favTutorial() {
    var mylist = document.getElementsByClassName("ddclass")[0];
    document.getElementsByClassName("input-large")[0].value = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
  }
})()
```

```html
<div class="widget-content-wrapper">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <form class="input-compressed">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="offscreen">
        Add a Tag
      </legend>
      <div class="editable-field-change">
        <span class="input-append input-smaller"><input class="input-large" data-link="proposedTag" placeholder="Add a tag (any text)..." size="16" type="text">
</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tags">
        <ul class="unstyled editable-list inline-list"></ul>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

That being said, your code is doing some ***very odd*** things. Why do you repeatedly try and create the `select` element, and exiting from the function when it already exists after the first iteration?

I would assume from the context that this is a rudimentary method of checking the DOM to see if a dynamic element has been created from some external source. If this is the case, use a `MutationObserver` instead.

Also, avoid generating HTML in your JS code. Put it in `<template />` elements and clone it. This way there is never any HTML logic within the JS.

Here's a full working example of this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // define MutationObserver to check the DOM for new .widget-content-wrapper elements being created
  var newWidgetContainerObserver = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(m => {
      m.addedNodes.forEach(n => {
        if (n.className === 'widget-content-wrapper')
          createSelectForWidget(n);
      });
    });
  });
  newWidgetContainerObserver.observe(document, { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree: true });

  let widgetContainer = document.querySelector('#widget-container');

  // when a new .widget-content-wrapper node is added to the DOM by external
  // code, append the select to it.
  let createSelectForWidget = node => {
    let selectTemplate = document.querySelector('#dd-template').content.cloneNode(true);
    let container = node.querySelector('.arrow');
    let html = container.appendChild(selectTemplate);
    container.addEventListener('change', favTutorial);
  }

  // event handler for the dynamically created select element, which sets 
  // the value of the related input 
  let favTutorial = e => {
    let select = e.target;
    let container = select.closest('.widget-content-wrapper');
    container.querySelector('.input-large').value = select.value;
  }

  // only for this demo, generates content on button click - mocking the  
  // external process which is updating your DOM
  document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let widgetClone = document.querySelector('#widget-template').content.cloneNode(true);
    widgetContainer.appendChild(widgetClone);
  });
})()
```

```html
<button id="test">Test - dynamically append new widget</button>

<div id="widget-container"></div>

<template id="widget-template">
  <div class="widget-content-wrapper">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <form class="input-compressed">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="offscreen">Add a Tag</legend>
        <div class="editable-field-change">
          <span class="input-append input-smaller"><input class="input-large" data-link="proposedTag" placeholder="Add a tag (any text)..." size="16" type="text">
  </span>
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
          <ul class="unstyled editable-list inline-list"></ul>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="dd-template">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <select class="ddclass" id="ddid">
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
      <option value="option3">option3</option>
      <option value="option4">option4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```